# In php, Is it possible to create two input box with same name?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, inputbox

In php, i have some input boxes in a form tag

Is it possible to create two input box with same name?
Is there any problem while the form is submitted?

Comment: Just as an addendum to all the answers, it is the "ID" field that you cannot have two of the same, that will cause problems in an HTML form.

Comment: Do you really mean "in PHP" or "in HTML".... it's possible to create ___any___ output in PHP, whether valid or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to create two input box with same name?

Yes. Element ids must be unique, but names do not.

> Is there any problem while the form is submitted?

PHP will discard all but the last one unless the name ends in `[]`.

```
<input name="foo[]">
<input name="foo[]">
```

will be accessible via

```
$_POST['foo'] # an array
```

Answer (score 1):

there is always the possibility to use array like syntax e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="my-field[]">
<input type="text" name="my-field[]">
```

in php you can access it using something like

```
$_REQUEST['my-field'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create with array parameter.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="txtname[]">
    <input type="text" name="txtname[]">
</form>
```

You will get value using `$_REQUEST['txtname']` which is `array`.

Comment: Hello! I noticed that you end your all answers with a “Thanks”, unfortunatly this is discouraged here on SO to leave place for the actual contents of your answer. Have a look at this Meta Post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/174540

Also: Check your formatting before you submit your answer. You accidentally put your text inside the code block as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may add the array bracket [] onto each input box. like this;

```
<form method="post" action="somepage.php">
<input type="text" name="box[]">
<input type="text" name="box[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then on somepage.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
     echo $_POST['box'][0];
     echo $_POST['box'][1];
  }
?>
```

The [] makes two boxes to be submitted as an array